# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC / C# : model sent to controller is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

Here is the markup of my form:

```
<form asp-controller="Group" asp-action="Create" class="new-group-form">
    <div class="input-section">
        <label asp-for="NewGroup.Name">Name</label>
        <input asp-for="NewGroup.Name" type="text">
    </div>

    <input class="invited-members" asp-for="NewGroup.Members" type="hidden" value="">

    <div class="possible-members">
        @foreach (var friend in Model.Friends)
        {
             <div class="member">
                 <p>@friend.FriendEmail</p>
                 <button id="@friend.FriendEmail" type="button" class="member__action invite">Invite</button>
             </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="create">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then this is the code of the controller:

```
[Route("group/new-group")]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromForm]NewGroupViewModel newGroupViewModel)
{
    var memberEmails = newGroupViewModel.Members.Split().ToArray();
    var ownerEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    if (ModelState.IsValid && memberEmails.Length >= 3)
    {
        var newGroup = _db.Groups.Add(new Group
        {
            Name = newGroupViewModel.Name,
            OwnerId = int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
        });

        _db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var member in memberEmails)
        {
            _db.GroupParticipants.Add(new GroupParticipant
            {
                UserId = _db.Users.First(x => x.Email == member).Id,
                GroupId = newGroup.Entity.Id,
                IsOwner = (member == ownerEmail)
            });
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Boards");
}
```

As you can see I already used tag `FromBody`, which does not seem to be helpful enough.

Here is the code of my model class:

```
public class NewGroupViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Members { get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is that `newGroupViewModel` values are null, and that leads to an exception at line

```
var memberEmails = newGroupViewModel.Members.Split().ToArray();
```

and the rest of the controller's code is kinda useless for this topic.

Due to the fact that null value can not be split. By the way inputs values are correct. But the values can't be successfully be delivered to the controller's method.

As you can see I've tried using `FromForm` tag, but it didn't help. Also I tried to reformat minor stuff as swapping some positioning of asp tags in inputs & labels (I've faced this problem before and that's how it was solved, but it doesn't work this time)

Comment: `MinLength` and `MaxLength` are for EF - for ASP.NET ViewModels you need to use `[StringLength]` (which supports both min and max lengths too).

Comment: well thanks for tip for sure, but it does not help in this very problem

Comment: What do you see in your browser's DevTools' Network tab? Is your `<form>` element rendered with `method="post"`? When you set a breakpoint on the first line in the `Create` action method what do you see in `this.Request.Form` in your debugger?

Comment: <form method="post" class="new-group-form active" action="/group/new-group">
thats how rendered form looks like.
and yes, as I already mentioned, hidden input (for members) is getting correct values in devtools.
saying about this.Request.Form I see 3 keys: NewGroup.Name, NewGroup.Members + verification token

Comment: I think thats important to clarify that method recieves the model itself. But NewGroup.Name, NewGroup.Members are null. Made sure in it while debugging.

Comment: What property is named `NewGroup`? Is `NewGroupViewModel` the same as the `@model` type in your `.cshtml` page? You can only use `asp-for=""` (or `Html.AnythingFor( m => m.Foo )` when the form's model is also the `@model` for the view (yes, this is a dumb limitation of ASP.NET MVC, but there are workarounds).

Comment: If I uderstood you right then ```public class BoardsViewModel
{
    public NewGroupViewModel NewGroup { get; set; }``` thats the part of model from file, where error with form occured. and.. yeah. they are same (sorry for my poor english knowledge btw :(     )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net Core bind value by property names. In your View code, You use `asp-for="NewGroup.Name"` tag helper in `input` tag, This tag helper will generate `name="NewGroup.Name"` in html automatically. So when you submit the from, the property names are `NewGroup.Name` and `NewGroup.Members`.

[image]

In your backend, you use `NewGroupViewModel` to accept data, But the property names in `NewGroupViewModel` are `Name` and `Members`, They can't match with `NewGroup.Name` and `NewGroup.Members`, So `NewGroupViewModel` can't bind data.
In your ajax code, you specify property names are `name` and `members`, This is why backend can bind value from ajax code.

So in your view code, you just need to specify the `name` attribute correctly, Then backend can bind the value successfully

```
<div class="input-section">
        <label asp-for="NewGroup.Name">Name</label>
        <input name="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <input class="invited-members" name="Members" type="hidden" value="xxxx">
```

**BTW:** Asp.Net Core MVC default bind value from form, So you don't need to add `[FromForm]` attribute in your controller action.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So I have to use ```name``` tag directly (without using ```asp-for```) in my input forms when request (```NewGroupViewModel``` in this case) is a property of a model, but not the model itself?

Answer (score -2):

Solved with help of ajax-request

```
function createGroup(name, members) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "group/new-group",
        data: {
            name: name,
            members: members
        }
    });
}
```

Still have no idea why does it not work in the old way